# Calculating acceleration of a particle from Radiation Pressure

Tags: electromagnetism, forces, electromagnetic-radiation, acceleration

I am trying to calculate the the acceleration of a particle from radiation pressure, assuming all radiation is absorbed. I got $$\Delta \vec{p} = \frac{\Delta U}{c_0}$$ and the intensity $I_S$=$1367 \ \frac{W}{m^2}$.

I think that $\Delta U = I_S A$. Since $\vec{p}_0=0$,  I get $$\vec{p}=\frac{I_S A}{c_0}=m \dot{x}$$ Now I am trying to find a way to calculate the acceleration. Since $$\vec{F}=\dot{\vec{p}}=m \ddot{x}=ma$$ I tried to do $$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{dt}} \frac{I_S A}{c_0} = 0 \quad \mathrm{???}$$ Obviously I can not get the derivate of that part of the equation with respect to $t$. I know there is some correlation with $I_S$ (because its unit is $\frac{W}{m^2} = \frac{\frac{kg m^2}{s^3}}{m^2}$) and time, but I don't know how to differentiate that equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total energy $\delta U$ is also proportional to time. So, the energy deposited is $I\times Area\times time$ given that the radiation is falling normally on the body. Else you have to take a $cos\theta$ component.Now, it's trivial to see that the acceleration will be constant if the intensity is constant.